# How to select a button as default button of the form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a form that takes user input and then let the user get connected to the SQL-Server.

This is happening on `Button.Click`. But where can I set the property Default button so that when the user clicks <kbd>Enter</kbd> it does the work of that button.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

It is called `AcceptButton` now on the form; set that to the button that will be the default button.
Refer to [Form.AcceptButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 22):

I think you want the "AcceptButton" property at the FORM level...   That will expose a combobox of available controls on your form, then select your "button" you want to use as the "Default" button on enter.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Form.AcceptButton property the "OK" button must have the TabOrder property set to 0 and all other controls within the form should have a TabOrder >0.

This can be done using a form resouce contruction kit or by code eg.
buttonOK.TabOrder = 0;

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed severally how there is a mix up when it comes to an active button and an accept button. I just came out of it. So, I just thought I add a little option to the answers already given. Obviously, the best answer is;

`this.AcceptButton = AcceptButton;`

However, if you wish to have the button as an active control, this is what you do;

`this.ActiveControl = OkButton;`

details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol?view=netcore-3.1

I hope it is helpful to anyone searching.