# Button to be selected by default

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two buttons in my form, in which one should be defaultly selected. How can i do that. For eg there are buttons pay by cash and pay by card, in which pybycash should be highlighted by default

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default button property in winform app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280221/default-button-property-in-winform-app)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], because we dont even know what gui framework you're using.

Comment: Actuallt Accept Button and Radio button concept both will work, but as i am wroking with compact framework , I am unable to use these classes . I dono whether Radio button can be used in compact framework

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `AcceptButton` for your form to whichever button you want to be the default button.

You can do this in code or in the Form Designer.

Answer (score 1):

So you want a RadioButton behaviour:

- Use a `GroupBox` and place some `RadioButtons` in it.
- On one `RadioButton` set `Checked` property to `True`

If you don't want it to look like a `RadioButton` you can change the apperance:

```
myRadioButton.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

Comment: Thanx. But i want normal buttons, not radio buttons

Comment: If the user can only select one then you should use RadioButtons. The styl e can be changed. Normal buttons don't have the 'only one selected' behaviour

Comment: User can only select one, but it should not be radio button. the need is for only normal button. But one button should be highlighted (which may be due to the more prefernce to that option )

Comment: Thats what I said, use a radiobutton (behaviour) and set the appearce to a normal button. I've updated the question. If you use normal buttons you manually have to select/deselect other buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much , I will use this concept , I will use the class from compact framework